# Not enough arguments for method unmarshal: (implicit evidence$1: spray.httpx.unmarshalling.FromResponseUnmarshaller

Tags: scala, spray, argonaut

I am passing from SprayJsonSupport to argonaut based on [this example](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/release/1.3/examples/spray-client/simple-spray-client/src/main/scala/spray/examples/Main.scala).
After some code modification :

```
object ElevationJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val locationCodec: CodecJson[Elevation] = casecodec2(Elevation, Elevation.unapply)("location", "elevation")
  implicit val elevationCodec: CodecJson[Location] = casecodec2(Location, Location.unapply)("lat", "lng")
  implicit def googleApiResultCodec: CodecJson[GoogleApiResult] = casecodec2(GoogleApiResult, GoogleApiResult.unapply)("status", "results")
}
```

I got this error

> Error:(41, 42) not enough arguments for method unmarshal: (implicit evidence$1: spray.httpx.unmarshalling.FromResponseUnmarshaller[GoogleApiResult])spray.http.HttpResponse => GoogleApiResult.
>   Unspecified value parameter evidence$1.
>     val pipeline = sendReceive ~> unmarshal[GoogleApiResult]
>                                            ^

I take a look at the unmarshall method:

```
 def unmarshal[T](implicit evidence$1 : spray.httpx.unmarshalling.FromResponseUnmarshaller[T]) : scala.Function1[spray.http.HttpResponse, T]
```

How can I add the implicit parameter? and why I did not got such error whith the sprayJsonSupport ?

The hole code :

```
import spray.httpx.unmarshalling.FromResponseUnmarshaller

import scala.util.{Success, Failure}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.event.Logging
import akka.io.IO
import spray.json.{JsonFormat, DefaultJsonProtocol}
import spray.can.Http
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport
import spray.client.pipelining._
import spray.util._
import argonaut._, Argonaut._

case class Elevation(location: Location, elevation: Double)
case class Location(lat: Double, lng: Double)
case class GoogleApiResult(status: String, results: List[Elevation])

object ElevationJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val locationCodec: CodecJson[Elevation] = casecodec2(Elevation, Elevation.unapply)("location", "elevation")
  implicit val elevationCodec: CodecJson[Location] = casecodec2(Location, Location.unapply)("lat", "lng")
  implicit def googleApiResultCodec: CodecJson[GoogleApiResult] = casecodec2(GoogleApiResult, GoogleApiResult.unapply)("status", "results")
}

object Main extends App {
  // we need an ActorSystem to host our application in
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("simple-spray-client")
  import system.dispatcher // execution context for futures below
  val log = Logging(system, getClass)

  log.info("Requesting the elevation of Mt. Everest from Googles Elevation API...")

  import ElevationJsonProtocol._

  val pipeline = sendReceive ~> unmarshal[GoogleApiResult]

  val responseFuture = pipeline (
    Get("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=27.988056,86.925278&sensor=false")
    )

  responseFuture onComplete {
    case Success(GoogleApiResult(_, Elevation(_, elevation) :: _)) =>
      log.info("The elevation of Mt. Everest is: {} m", elevation)
      shutdown()

    case Success(somethingUnexpected) =>
      log.warning("The Google API call was successful but returned something unexpected: '{}'.", somethingUnexpected)
      shutdown()

    case Failure(error) =>
      log.error(error, "Couldn't get elevation")
      shutdown()
  }

  def shutdown(): Unit = {
    IO(Http).ask(Http.CloseAll)(1.second).await
    system.shutdown()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really use argonaut, I use play json with spray. But at a glance it seems like there needs to be an argonaut support trait/import pulled in for your implicit codecs to convert to spray's unmarshaller (similar thing is required for play json).

https://github.com/dwhjames/argonaut-spray

this library seems to be what you want. Your implicits and imports look fine, pulling in the library should solve your problem.